# How to determine when all scripts finished running?

Tags: javascript, performance, browser

I am using Javascript and jQuery to render a page.

The page has to be loaded very quickly. Therefore I  would like to render some basic info first and only after that send another request to get some additional info.

My question is when should I send that second request? How do I know when the basic info has completely finished rendering and no scripts are still running?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using the `$.ajax()` method. So look at the docs and you'll see the `success` option you can use to run code when a request has successfully finished.

Comment: i think there multiple requests with their own handlers and want to know when all are finished...

Comment: Do the scripts associated with the basic information do any asynchronous processing such as ajax? If not, you can be confident they all run in exactly the order they're included in and you can put your code that loads the additional information immediately after the last of the other scripts. Put the scripts at the end of the body and you can be confident all the basic content has loaded before they run.

Comment: would that be a case to use `setTimeout(..., 0)` ?

Comment: Regular scripts in the page execute in order, and each script tag only execute once the previous one has finished executing. The entire dom structure up to that script tag will be available. Close this question NOW

Comment: Why bother? When you delay the additional request your page will appear to be loading slower when you don't know it's intentional. Just load everything you need as quick as possible.

Answer (score 3):

May be better would be use [AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) approach? Besides requirejs there is similar [lib](https://github.com/cujojs/curl) that me liked.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/)

Answer (score -2):

```
var asyncOperations = {
    counter: -1, // -1 because the value should not already met the ending condition at initialization
    finishedHandler: null;
    startOp: function() {
         if(counter == -1) counter = 0;
         counter++;
    },
    endOp: function() {
         counter++;
         if(counter == 0 && finishedHandler) {
             finishedHandler.inform();
    }
}

function handler(data) {
     doSomethingWithData();
     asyncOperations.endOp();
}

function allOperationsFinished() {
    alert("success");
}

function main() {
    asyncOperations.finishedHandler = allOperationsFinished;
    $.ajax(...whatever..., handler);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Set up a semaphore that you can check with a timer. Say you have 5 scripts running. Set a global variable `finishedRunning=0;`. In each script, just before returning (ie finishing) do `finishedRunning+=1;`. When `finishedRunning` reaches 5, you are good to go.

Comment: with *timer* you mean *counter*? and it would be better if he starts the counter at 0, when starting the script counter+1 and when finishing -1

Comment: Nope. A timer. Which can check the `finishedRunning` variable every second or so.

Comment: What if one of the scripts has some error and `finishedRunning` never gets to `5`?

Comment: checking every x seconds could be a bottleneck... @nnnnnn: +1

Comment: Not for long, unless it's long-running scripts. But the OP mentioned it was basic stuff.

Comment: @nnnnnn Proper code (ie exception catching) would take care of it too.